# Compiler Error CS0012 appear only in VS 2022

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022

Error: "The type 'type' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'assembly'"

Error appear only in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.4.
In the version Visual Studio 2019 v.16.11.23 compiles without errors.
Project version: .Net Framework 4.7.2.

The project does not have access to the .dll project references that has a direct reference

Sample:

Interface from ProjectA:

`public interface ITestA {}`

Interface from ProjectB

`public interface ITestB : ITestA { }`

ProjectC with error:

```
    {
        var test = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITestB>();
    }
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwZMT.png)

When I add direct reference to ProjectA error disappear but I don't want to add additional references.

I assume that I don't need to add all references to project directly, If I added reference to ProjectB dll with ProjectA it should be created automatically in bin directory. This is how it works in Visual Studio 2019.

Please advice, is this a common behavior of VS 2022 or are additional settings required when compiling?

Answer (score 0):

We observe the same issue at our site:
Classic .Net framework projects.
Target framework of project files: .Net Framework 4.8
Visual Studio Build Tools: 2022

Direct project references are resolved, indirect not.

MSBuild version 17.6.3+07e294721 for .NET Framework
error CS0012: The type 'xxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'yyy'

When adding the indirectly referenced project its working, but this is not in our scope.